# Are there any agressive CSS Minification tools?

Tags: css, node.js, compression

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a tool that will aggressively rewrite CSS to compress styles more efficiently.  e.g. I'd like:

```
.foo { color : red; font-size: 16px; height: 20px; }
.bar { color : red; font-size: 16px; height: 30px; }
```

to be compressed to:

```
.foo, .bar { color : red; font-size : 16px; }
.foo { height : 20px; }
.bar { height : 30px; }
```

To be clear, all the minifiers I know of, like YUI Compressor, only remove white-space and possibly join a few properties (like `font-family` and `font-size` into `font`).  I'm looking for something that's willing to do a complete re-write of the structure of a file.

Short of that, if anyone knows of any work anyone has done with regards to the compression logic behind this, that info would be appreciated.  I'm thinking of writing my own if I can't find one, but there's a million things to consider, like `margin-top` over-writing part of `margin`, selector specificity & include order, etc etc etc...  Then the job of how to efficiently compress the info, like will it be more efficient to repeat a selector or a property?

Comment: I'm sure there is one, but if you did write your own, a good starting point to get around things like the `margin-top` issue you mentioned would be to expand it out fully before trying to compact - i.e. expand margin to all 4 full rules first. You're right though, it wouldn't be a small undertaking.

Comment: I would call this "optimization" rather than minification.

Comment: Sounds like a kind of "reverse LessCSS"

Comment: Very interesting topic. I have an oss project (http://github.com/mwrock/RequestReduce) that creates sprites from css bg images. It requires alot of css parsing. Recently i added the ability to find any selector that is "derrivable" from another in an ordered list by css specificity. This gave me the idea to write a new minifier that does just this. From what I can tell nothing does this and it would be super cool. It could also find dupe selectors and aggregate their properties or delete selectors overridden later in css. Have not started yet but good to see someone else is interested.

Comment: @MattWrock -- My version of the same thing: https://github.com/cwolves/stylus-images :)  Though it's built on top of stylus, not straight css.  I was thinking of building this on top of stylus' engine since it is already a full CSS parser and I can get a tree out of it after parsed.  Then convert that tree into two hashes: one from selectors-->properties, one properties-->selectors.  Then start trying to compress in both directions, and taking the result with better compression each time.  PM me on github if you're interested in collaborating on this.

Comment: @MattWrock -- One of the main reasons I want this is to remove dupe selectors, etc.  I feel like I could often hand-compress CSS to <50% of its original size, but it would take forever.

Comment: Just a small note... please work together on this! ;) There is a large community there that would be thrilled!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know any aggressive CSS minification tool, but you could use the following approach:

### Setup

1. Expand your CSS (`margin:1px 0 0 0;` to `margin-top:1px; margin-left:0px;`...).
2. Build a graph G = (V,E) with V as set of vertices and E as set of edges:

   - V consists of the conjunction of the two sets A (unique selectors, eg. `div`, `p > span`, `#myid`) and B (unique properties, eg. `display:block;`, `color:#deadbeef;`).
   - E consists of all associations between a selector (in A) and a property (in B).
3. Use an appropriate weight function `c` for your elements in `b`. This could be the number of neighbors of a given element `b`, or `accumulated lenght of properties - accumulated length of selectors`. Your choice.

You may notice that by using this approach you'll get a bipartite graph. Now try the following greedy algorithm (pseudo code):

### Algorithm

1. Take an element *b* in *B* that has maximum weight and add it to an empty set *Z*
2. Check whether another element d in B has same weight

   - if such a d exists check whether it covers the same selectors.

     1. If *d* covers the same selectors: add *d* to *Z* and go to step 2.
     2. if *d* does not cover the same selectors check the next element with the same weight or go to step 3 if you checked all elements *d*.
3. Now *Z* is a set of properties covering some selectors. Parse this as CSS into a buffer.
4. Delete all elements in *Z* and their adjacent edges in G and delete *Z* itself.
5. If B is not empty go to step 1.
6. Your buffer contains a pre-minified CSS code. You can now merge some properties (eg. `margin-top:0px;margin-left:1px`).

### Remarks

Please note that the actual compression depends on your weight function. As it is a greedy algorithm it will likely return a minified CSS, but I believe someone will post a counterexample. Note also that you have to update your weight function after deleting the elements in *Z*.

### Runtime estimate

The algorithm will always terminate and will run in O(`|B|^2*|A|`) if I'm not mistaken. If you use a heap and sort the properties in each adjacency list (setup time O(`|B|*|A|log(|A|)`)) you'll get O(`|B|*|A|* (log(|B|)+log(|A|))`).

Comment: Awesome, thank you for this write-up.  I haven't studied DSA in about 10 years, so it is very helpful.  I still need to wrap my head around exactly how much is possible, however, considering that CSS specificity plays a large role in how things render on page.  I believe the rules around this are simple: Anything with different specificities can be moved around at will.  Anything with the same specificity level has to be kept in the original order.  But I need to sit down and verify that for myself :)

Comment: @cwolves: It's been almost a year - were you able to create a minification tool?

Answer (score 3):

[CSS Tidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/) works like a champ!

- colours like "black" or rgb(0,0,0) are converted to #000000 or rather #000 if possible.
- Some hex-codes are replaced by their colour names if they are shorter.
- a{property:x;property:y;} becomes a{property:y;}
- (all duplicate properties are merged) margin:1px 1px 1px 1px; becomes margin:1px;
- margin:0px; becomes margin:0;
- a{margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;} becomes
- a{margin:10px;}
- margin:010.0px; becomes margin:10px;
- all unnecessary whitespace is removed
- depending on the compression-level all background-properties are merged
- all comments are removed
- the last semicolon in every block can be removed
- missing semicolons are added
- incorrect newlines in strings are fixed
- missing units are added
- bad colors (and color names) are fixed
- property:value ! important; becomes property:value !important;

Comment: It doesn't do what I asked, it only removes whitespace.

Comment: No it does not. It changes #334455 to #345 among others.

Comment: In fact, had you read the first page on their site you would clearly see that. Gonna update answer accordingly.

Comment: Okay, it does a few others, but it won't actively re-write selectors, properties, etc...

Comment: Absolutely agreed! ;) Should have looked at your rep prior to answering, though it to be a newby question.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the downvote. Even though my answer doesn't hit the nail it's much more accurate than @Chris Foster's answer... which wasn't downvoted. It also makes me wonder when the downvoter does not leave a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)?

Comment: It doesn't do what I asked, it only removes whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can also  use http://www.minifycss.com/css-compressor/  or  http://www.ventio.se/tools/minify-css/

Comment: Those don't do what I asked, they only remove whitespace.

Comment: minifycss does sorting of selectors and properties

Answer (score 0):

A project called [CSS Tools](https://github.com/rflynn/css-tools) claims to do this.