# How to minify HTML with CSS and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, compression

I have a .html document with CSS and Javascript inside of document (no external files). Is there some online tool that would ***minify*** document and Javascript to some very small footprint? I saw many scripts kind of unreadable, where all variables and function names are replaced with one-letter names, etc. Please advice.

Comment: I think the keyword you are looking for here is "minify"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit 2 (Feb 22, 2017):** Now the best tool to minify your assets (and a whole lot more, by adding loaders and plugins) is definitely [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org).

Example of config to move all your `.css` in one file and minify it:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        minimize: true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**Edit 1 (Sept 16, 2014):** Even better, now you have *task runners* like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

> Task runners are small applications that are used to automate many of
>   the time consuming, boring (but very important) tasks that you have to
>   do while developing a project. These include tasks such as running
>   tests, concatenating files, minification, and CSS preprocessing. By
>   simply creating a task file, you can instruct the task runner to
>   automatically take care of just about any development task you can
>   think of as you make changes to your files. It’s a very simple idea
>   that will save you a lot of time and allow you to stay focused on
>   development.

Must read: [Getting started with Gulp.js](http://markgoodyear.com/2014/01/getting-started-with-gulp/)

Example of task with JavaScript concatenation and minification (and JSHint):

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/scripts/**/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/js'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/js'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts task complete' }));
});
```

---

**Original answer (Jul 19, 2012):** I advise the [HTML5 Boilerplate Build Script](https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script) which can minify your JS and CSS.

Answer (score 7):

Good javascript compressor is also [Google's Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) and vice versa, to make compressed code a bit better readible you can use [Javascript Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/). You can also have a look at [phpEasyMin](http://phpeasymin.com/) project.

Answer (score 5):

[Closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) has been correctly recommended for JS; but not many are aware of Google's *[Closure stylesheets](http://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/)*. One of the closure stylesheets features is renaming, where

```
<style>
  .descriptive-parent-class-name .descriptive-element-class-name {color:red;}
</style>
<div class="descriptive-parent-class-name">
  <p class="descriptive-element-class-name">Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p class="descriptive-element-class-name">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

would become

```
<style>
  .a-b .a-c {color:red;}
</style>
<div class="a-b">
  <p class="a-c">Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p class="a-c">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

There'll be further minification too; and given the fact that OP indicates all resources are included into the html, this may end up saving quite a bit in traffic overhead.

NB: if you inspect any Google search results page, you'll see their class and ID names are almost never longer than 4 random characters

Answer (score 3):

By using one of the [many](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/) [available](http://www.minifyjavascript.com/) [minifiers](http://jscompress.com/).

There are [even](http://www.minifycss.com/css-compressor/) [some](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) that minify CSS.

Comment: But javascript minifiers would not change function names to one-letter names if are used by document, such as `onload="pageLoad"` - then `pageLoad` stays :-/

Comment: Some minifiers have the option of selecting whether or not to minify literals/function names/variable names.

Comment: But so far I always found just non-complex minifiers. I would like to use some that take care of all parts: js, css, html

Comment: You're most likely going to have to use a combination of tools, I doubt there's any fire-and-forget toolkit out there.

Comment: I downvoted your post because you are suggesting the op should be forced to use more than one tool.  There are language aware tools that can minify code in various languages in a single pass.  I posted below about a tool called Pretty Diff, for example.

Comment: There is also the Microsoft AJax Minifier
http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid you'll have to do it in two steps:

1. manual search and replace of global objects in a text editor
2. minifiers to finish the job on css and js

I had a similar question some time ago (about global objects and object keys). The answer I got was that no tool will make assumptions about the global context. In your example, they won't minify "pageLoad" because it might be used by another html or js fragment you didn't provide.

A workaround in your example would be to make the pageLoad function local and add the onload event dynamically in the script:

```
elt.onload=function(){pageLoad();};
```

Answer (score 1):

While JavaScript code can be compressed and decompressed within JavaScript (see other answers), it's actually hard to achieve the same result in CSS. There is currently no tool that will do more than remove unnecessary whitespace (see also [Are there any agressive CSS Minification tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917322/are-there-any-agressive-css-minification-tools)), since identifier and class names cannot be changed without destroying the link between HTML and CSS.

Also, you can't remove anything from HTML markup except whitespace. Well, you could minify the class names and identifier, but there's currently no tool that will update those minified values in your CSS/JS files, so this would render your website ugly and broken. And even empty elements are often needed in order to get some CSS effects right (yes, I'm looking at you, IE6). This applies to JavaScript function names too.

TL;DR: Unfortunately there's no all-in-one-minify-everything tool. The closest thing is [htmlcompressor](http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/).

Comment: What I would expect is to replace function names in html and then also in Javascript. As for now, for example, if you have `onload=pageLoad`, then this name of function will stay that size, but it would be nice to have it replace by some short (one-two letter) name. So there is some potentilal beyond whitespace compression...

Comment: Well, it's basically the same problem with CSS/HTML - you have to change the function names everywhere and watch out for collisions.

Answer (score 1):

Try [http://prettydiff.com/](http://prettydiff.com/?m=minify).  It offers automatic language detection and can minify html, css, and javascript.  This tool presumes that script tags without a mime type or with a javascript relevant mime type must contain either javascript or nothing.  Likewise, style tags without a mime type or with the "text/css" mime type are presumed to contain CSS.  The CSS and JavaScript are minified accordingly.  The tool itself is written in javascript.  There is no reason you should have to use more than one tool.

Comment: It does not rename for example classes, etc. - by doing that (if...) it would make result much shorter

Comment: Correct, renaming is not minification.  That is obfuscation.  The objective of minification is not to harm, with exception to comments, the ability to read the document after use of a beautification tool.  A good minifier will not rename anything or alter the functionality of the javascript or css and leave the entire document's code on a single line with only the minimum amount of white space without impact to the content.

Answer (score 0):

Have never tried it but have heard real good reviews of Google's Closure compiler..You may want to try it out

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try [WebMarkupMin Online](http://webmarkupmin.apphb.com/).

The WebMarkupMin Online a free online tools to minify your HTML, XHTML and XML code. HTML and XHTML minifiers supports the minification of CSS code from `style` tags and attributes, and minification of JavaScript code from `script` tags, event attributes and hyperlinks with `javascript:` pseudo-protocol. These minifiers supports multiple algorithms of CSS minification (Mads Kristensen's [Efficient stylesheet minifier](http://madskristensen.net/post/Efficient-stylesheet-minification-in-C.aspx), [Microsoft Ajax CSS Minifier](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/) and [YUI CSS Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)) and JavaScript minification (Douglas Crockford's [JSMin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html), [Microsoft Ajax JS Minifier](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/) and [YUI JS Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)).

These tools is based on [WebMarkupMin](http://webmarkupmin.codeplex.com/) library.