# Size of Html page and Response speed

Tags: html, jakarta-ee

I have written a applicaiton where it has to process lots of data, lots of  loops and then it has to generate an html page as it has to show all the data.The html page size it  generated was 5.5mb due you think is it valid or its completely stupid .Any alternate solutions.The time to display was 15  min

Comment: We can't answer this with what little information you give, but a 5.5MB HTML page is likely to be stupid. :)

Comment: well a webpage representing a farm where seeds are sowed in rows and columns manner this web page is used to about 1000 seeds

Comment: of corse we dont show all 1000 seeds at a time it depends on locatin user selects location .Each location has about 200 seeds.All the other 800 seeds data are hidden

Comment: You may be able to split the data and load only the needed parts using Ajax. That might bring loading times down.

Answer (score 0):

How about limiting the number of rows per page and adding pagination?

For this to be user friendly, you will need to sort the data in some sort of way (which you should anyway) and you'll have to add some kind of search/filter implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [How to minify HTML with CSS and Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568874/how-to-minify-html-with-css-and-javascript), this [JavaScript implementation of Gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip) and after these, go to this one post [Gzip versus minify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807119/gzip-versus-minify).

I hope this help!

Comment: there is nothgin complex javascript code or css it   just plain html

Comment: It's not about complexity, it's all about reducing the amount of data. Some say if you minify and gzip all your resources, you may reduce something like 80% of this amount (~4.4MB less data in your case).

Take a look at this and check the numbers.
http://beerpla.net/2009/06/09/how-to-make-your-site-lightning-fast-by-compressing-deflategzip-your-html-javascript-css-xml-etc-in-apache/